# How to remove half of the values stored in list in tickle

Tags: list, element

I have very basic question, not getting clue to make of it.

Let say i have a variable whose datatype is list and contains 10 elements. Now i want to do some opeartion and want only 5 elements from the list. But this  elements of the variable is not same everytime. This is used in loop in which everytime reading new line different number of elements are storing in the variable and i want half of it.

Eg:

```
set a {a b c d e f g h i j k l} //(12 elements)
```

then I want some automatic operation through which i will get

```
set a {a b c d e f} //(This is half of the 12 elements -> 6 elements)
```

Answer (score -1):

A precise answer would depend on the language you're using, but the general approach I would suggest is to get the length of the list, halve it, and use the resulting value as the bound of a for cycle in which you populate the smaller list.

```
int len = yourList.length();
int halvedLen = len / 2;
list halvedList = new list(halvedLen)
for(int i = 0; i < halvedLen; i++){
    list
}
```

Comment: Well this is in C or tickle? It will save my time if you provide tickle supported format Thanks in advance

Comment: Neither of the two, this is just some pseudo-code I came up with. I don't know Tickle, but implementing this kind a solution should be quite straightforward if you have some basic knowledge of the language.